# Try to prove a surface is ruled

Tags: algebraic-geometry

Suppose that $X$ is a projective smooth surface. And $C$ is a irreducible curve on $X$ s.t. $C\simeq \mathbb{P}^1$ and $(C^2)=0$. Can we prove that there exists a morphism $\phi: X\rightarrow Y$ to a smooth projective curve such that $\phi_*O_X=O_Y$

Comment: See page 192 of https://www.springer.com/la/book/9783540008323

Comment: @AlanMuniz I can't really understand especially when h^0(C)>2. Do you have any other explanation for algebraic geometry?